# How to force a new line in ng-zorro-mobile's TabPane [title] property

Tags: ng-zorro-mobile

I'm very new to frontend development.
[TabPane from ng-zorro-mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fjif.png)

Currently I'm exploring ng-zorro-mobile, it's nice and clear.
I would like to know if there is a symbol or quick way to break a line.
e.g. I want to show the first line in Chinese and the second line in English

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd-mobile ?

Comment: yes, but I'm using the document https://ng.mobile.ant.design/#/components/tabs/en